# How to make lodash.tonumber work with import() and commonjs unit test in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

My tsconfig.json is:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    }
}
```

And because `lodash.tonumber` has no types, so I declared it like:

```
// lib.d.ts
declare module "lodash.tonumber" {
    function toNumber(value: any): number;
    export = toNumber;
}
```

Then I import the library like:

```
// index.ts
/// <reference path="./lib.d.ts" />
import toNumber from "lodash.tonumber";
export { toNumber }
```

It works perfectly with `import()` as expected.

When I want to add unit test for `index.ts`, because it runs at nodejs, so I should compile it with `tsconfig.json` like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    }
}
```

After I run the test, it shows the error: `lodash_tonumber_1.default is not a function`, the generate js file is:

```
// index.js
/// <reference path="./lib.d.ts" />
var lodash_tonumber_1 = require("lodash.tonumber");
exports.toNumber = lodash_tonumber_1.default;
```

The document said the `lodash.tonumber` should be used like:

```
const toNumber = require("lodash.tonumber");
console.log(toNumber("123"));
```

So the generated js file is wrong, my tsconfig.json may be wrong at somewhere, so what's wrong?

I tried to change code to:

```
// index.ts
/// <reference path="./lib.d.ts" />
import toNumber = require("lodash.tonumber");
export { toNumber }
```

For the unit test(module=commonjs) case, it generated correct `var toNumber = require("lodash.tonumber");`, and so it works;

But for my normal module=esnext build, it broke, because it didn't generate `import toNumber from "lodash.tonumber";`, the runtime error is `ReferenceError: toNumber is not defined`,

I also check the lodash.toNumber js code:

```
function toNumber(value) {
  if (typeof value == 'number') {
    return value;
  }
  ...
}

module.exports = toNumber;
```

So my types should be correct.

What can I do next?

Answer (score 0):

```
// lib.d.ts
declare module "lodash.tonumber" {
    function toNumber(value: any): number;
    export = toNumber;
    namespace toNumber { }
}
```

Declare a namespace with same name works.